# What is the name of the "text editor" at the top of the screen? (Picture included)

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-drawable

What is the name of the text editor that appears at the top the screen when you are using an EditText (when you begin using the Text Selector Handles)?  Here is a picture:

[image: Text editor]

Can this drawable be changed?  If so how?

I have tried searching "android text editor", "android edittext gui", and "android cut copy paste edittext" but have had no success.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is android's Contextual ActionBar.

See:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual

Answer (score 0):

That is Contextual Action Bars

See: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual

Answer (score 0):

That action bar is called Contextual Action Bar.
That is a temporary action bar that overlays the application's action bar for the duration of a particular subtask.
ie whenever we are copying any message from whatsapp messenger, when we click and hold a message a new action bar appears providing us different options like copy,delete etc.